# Оптимизирует ли компилятор GCC данную запись?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, c++11, gcc, компилятор

Речь пойдёт об инициализации объектов. Большинство делают это следующим образом:

```
A a;
```

или же

```
A a(args);
```

в случае передачи аргументов в конструктор.
Но что будет в случае записи, подобной используемой в C#? А именно:

```
A a = new A();
```

или же:

```
var a = new A();
```

в случае `C++` это выглядит как

```
A a = A();
```

или же:

```
auto a = A();
```

Но будет ли компилятор оптимизировать данную запись до обычного `A a();`, где, в отличии от моего предложенного варианта, нет оператора `=`?

Comment: Ни в одном из ваших вариантов нет "оператора `=`". Символ `=` в синтаксисе инициализации не имеет никакого отношения к "оператору `=`".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, во всех версиях спецификации С++ *инициализация копированием* при одинаковых типах левой и правой части сразу же рассматривается как *прямая инициализация*. То есть ваше

```
A a = A();
```

сразу же означает именно

```
A a(A()); // в условной записи, ведь на самом деле это объявление функции
```

К "оптимизациям" это пока не имеет никакого отношения.

Во-вторых, в С++11 будет ли этот вариант соптимизирован до

```
A a(); // в условной записи, ведь на самом деле это объявление функции
```

зависит от вашего компилятора. В любом случае, вы все равно обязаны предоставить доступный копирующий или перемещающий конструктор.

В-третьих, начиная с С++17 этот вопрос уже не имеет отношения к оптимизациям. В С++17 запись

```
A a = A();
```

сразу является просто альтернативной формой записи для

```
A a(); // в условной записи, ведь на самом деле это объявление функции
```

Answer (score 8):

Насколько я понимаю и помню новый стандарт, это в обязательном порядке превратится в

```
A a;
```

потому как `auto` выведет тип как `A`, а объявление

```
A a = A();
```

обязано быть соптимизировано просто в конструирование `a` без промежуточного копирования.

*"По-моему, так". (с) Пух*

Comment: То есть `A a = A();` будет превращено в `A a();`?

Comment: Насколько я помню, в С++17 оно обязано быть превращено, а до того - просто так будет на практике... Поигрался с VC++ 2017 - превращает в единственный вызов конструктора, как и требуется :)

Comment: А что на счёт компилятора `GCC`/`G++`?

Comment: Уверен, что точно так же :) Да, вдогонку на всякий случай: - знак равенства в объявлении означает не присваивание, а копирование. Т.е. даже в самом старом компиляторе будет вызываться не присваивание, а копирование.

Comment: Вот, https://ideone.com/iRSFka - убедитесь, что все так же и в GCC.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, ни в одном из предложенных вариантов нет оператора `=`.

Во-вторых, непонятно зачем так писать, ведь получается дублирование или излишества. Писать по аналогии с С# - явно не самая лучшая идея.

Ну, а в-третьих, стоит использовать синтаксис *list-initialization*:

```
A a{};
A a{args};
```